# MySql Use existing column to create and populate new column

Tags: sql, insert, new-operator, if-statement

I have a table with values. I am trying to create a new column whose row value will depend on that of an existing column. For example, in the table below, if the substr of the id column from index 6 to index 7 is greater than 10, then the value of the new column at that row should be the  sub string of the id at index 1-4 *hyphen* substr(id, 1, 4)+1. Else the value should be substr(id, 1, 4) -1 *hyphen* substr(id, 1, 4).

```
id          New Column  Name
M20061012   2006-2007   Jude
K20070212   2006-2007   Anne
D20071214   2007-2008   John
```

Here is the algorithm for each row of the table:

```
if substr(id, 5, 1) < 10
   New Column value at that row = substr(id, 1, 4) - substr(id, 1, 4)+1
else
   New Column value at that row = substr(id, 1, 4)-1 - substr(id, 1, 4)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

**EDIT:**
So I tried this as suggested by @scwagner

```
SELECT
id,
(CASE WHEN CONVERT(SUBSTR(id,6,2), SIGNED) < 10 
THEN CONCAT(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)-1,'-',CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)) 
ELSE CONCAT(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED),'-',CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)+1)   END) AS `New Column`,
Name
FROM new
```

Where new is the name of the table. But this returns a column with all row values = BLOB.
How can I fix that?

Comment: `if substr(id, 5, 1) < 10...` a 1-character substring containing a digit will ALWAYS be < 10.  Do you mean `substr(id, 5, 2)`?

Comment: Also, what database are you on (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, Posgreas...)?

Comment: Yes. I am using MySql. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to test this on more data, but this worked on MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.8 with the test data that you provided:

```
SELECT
  id,
  (CASE WHEN CONVERT(SUBSTR(id,6,2), SIGNED) < 10 THEN CONCAT(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)-1,'-',CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)) ELSE CONCAT(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED),'-',CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)+1) END) AS `New Column`,
  Name
FROM
  <your table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a column created with all values BLOB

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
 SELECT
    id,
    (CASE WHEN CONVERT(SUBSTR(id,6,2), SIGNED) < 10 
    THEN CONCAT(CAST(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)-1 AS CHAR),'-',CAST(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED) AS CHAR)) 
    ELSE CONCAT(CAST(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED) AS CHAR),'-',CAST(CONVERT(SUBSTR(id, 2, 4),SIGNED)+1) AS CHAR)   END) AS `New Column`,
    Name
    FROM new
```